# Dyanmic fragment that changes activity by static buttons

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'll start by showing what I'am trying to do with a picture, please take a look

[image]

As you can see I have three buttons that are in the main activity, when i press BTN_1 i want the fragment to initialize an activity lets call it Activity_A that has it's own layout and functions, same with BTN_2 and BTN_3 , each button starts a different activity, the buttons are static, they stay there forever.

Basically its one activity that is static that hold inside it a dynamic fragment that is dynamically changed to different activity's

I'm kind of lost here so any help would be more than thankful: tutorials,Code example,hints

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using API11+, I think you will be well served by the "Action Bar with Tabbed Navigation" pattern.  Google explains this pattern [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs), complete with example code.

If you need to support versions older than Honeycomb, you can do the same thing with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

The basic idea is that you have a single activity with tabs that are automatically placed appropriately based on screen size.  When a tab is hit, you can handle and respond by loading an appropriate Fragment into the content area of your app.